# Specific string in python requests.get gives ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Trying to get this specific page...

```
request = requests.get('http://market.yandex.ru/catalog/90555/list')
```

...gives me a strange error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py in read_chunked(self, amt)
    406                 try:
--> 407                     self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
    408                 except ValueError:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''
```

I figured out that some part of a string is to blame. I was experimenting with it and the results are even more weird:

```
# No error
http://market.ru/catalog/90555/list
http://market.yandex.ru/catalo

# Error
http://market.yandex.ru/catalog
```

P.S. By the way, the problem has occured today. Just recently I had no problems with getting this very page (using the same method).

Comment: Are you 100% certain you are not running with an older version of the library? Did you perhaps upgrade and forgot to restart? The source code in the traceback suggests the exception should have been caught instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  I had a similar issue, when I opened the page with my browser it asked to fill in a captcha with the message below

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but not the same traceback. I managed to load the page just fine in `requests` but if they implemented a rate limit that straight up violates the chunked transfer-encoding expectations then the `urllib3` library will raise an `IncompleteRead` exception right there. The `ValueError` exception makes not being caught makes no sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how the flock do you fill out the captcha?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I am not rate limited on my IP address. Not *yet*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I got limited after one request

Comment: @MartijnPieters @PadraicCunningham just updated my `requests`, restarted my system. Yes, `IncompleteRead` is beeing raised just after `ValueError`, forgot to mention it, sorry. Thought that it's just one of the consequences of `ValueError`. I tested some more pages of this resourse and a couple of them give the same error. I guess it's some anti-bot thing then.

Comment: @SereznoKot: it is, but badly implemented.

Comment: I'm not getting any captcha in a browser though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being rate limited, but the server does so in a way that violates the HTTP specification. Their response headers promise a *Chunked* transfer encoding, then do not send such a response.

If you look at the URL with `curl` in verbose mode, you get the following output:

```
$ curl -v https://market.yandex.ru/catalog/90555/list
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 213.180.204.22...
* Connected to market.yandex.ru (213.180.204.22) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: market.yandex.ru
* Server certificate: Certum Level IV CA
* Server certificate: Certum CA
> GET /catalog/90555/list HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: market.yandex.ru
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 18 May 2015 18:53:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=120
< X-Forwardtouser-Y: 1
< Set-Cookie: spravka=dD0xNDAwNDM5MTk1O2k9ODQuOTIuOTguMTcwO3U9MTQwMDQzOTE5NTUxNjUwOTExMjtoPWNkMzVlMzBlMjgxMTg4YWM0YjYyZDg3OTg4ZjUyNWFj; domain=.yandex.ru; path=/; expires=Wed, 17-Jun-2015 18:53:15 GMT
< Location: http://market.yandex.ru/showcaptcha?cc=1&retpath=http%3A//market.yandex.ru/catalog/90555/list%3F_bfd13d35fbf1551a835f050d3775fc4b&t=0/1431975195/029660aeb063916c78e30ebd9444fd4b&s=4dd645e7048b399008278208fa776ba9
< Set-Cookie: uid=CniLolVaNRthdR2JDtV0Ag==; path=/
< 
* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

The are sending you a *redirect*, but the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header in the response means that the client side has to load chunks, which are not there.

The redirect leads to a captcha:

```
http://market.yandex.ru/showcaptcha?cc=1&retpath=http%3A//market.yandex.ru/catalog/90555/list%3F_bfd13d35fbf1551a835f050d3775fc4b&t=0/1431975195/029660aeb063916c78e30ebd9444fd4b&s=4dd645e7048b399008278208fa776ba9
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```